# Creating a barplot from matrix

Tags: r

So, I have a matrix like that:

```
> dput(tbl_sum_peaks[1:40])
structure(c(2, 8, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
4, 2), .Names = c("AT1G01050", "AT1G01080", "AT1G01090", "AT1G01320", 
"AT1G01470", "AT1G01800", "AT1G01910", "AT1G01960", "AT1G01980", 
"AT1G02150", "AT1G02470", "AT1G02500", "AT1G02560", "AT1G02780", 
"AT1G02816", "AT1G02880", "AT1G02920", "AT1G02930", "AT1G03030", 
"AT1G03090", "AT1G03110", "AT1G03210", "AT1G03220", "AT1G03230", 
"AT1G03330", "AT1G03475", "AT1G03630", "AT1G03680", "AT1G03740", 
"AT1G03870", "AT1G04080", "AT1G04170", "AT1G04270", "AT1G04410", 
"AT1G04420", "AT1G04530", "AT1G04640", "AT1G04650", "AT1G04690", 
"AT1G04750"))
```

I would like to make a barplot which will have on `yaxis` the number of rows with specific number. As we see it the given example data most of the rows has a number 1 so the barplot for number 1 will be the tallest.

That's a basic but I can't turn on my brain... so help from someone will be rewarded!

Comment: If you are using `ggplot` `library(ggplot2); library(dplyr);as.data.frame(tbl_sum_peaks) %>% ggplot(., aes(factor(tbl_sum_peaks))) + geom_bar() + xlab(NULL) +ylab(NULL)`

Comment: That works pretty well as well. If I would like to make instead of that a lineplot with number of rows on xaxis and scale from 1 to 8 on yaxis

Comment: If that is the case, why your title is `barplot`.?

Comment: It is not the case. I need both so instead of creating new question I decided to ask here by comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
barplot(table(tbl_sum_peaks))
```

Comment: That's simple and works pretty well. If I would like to make instead of that a lineplot with number of rows on `xaxis` and scale from 1 to 8 on `yaxis`.

Comment: @lukeA I liked your answer

Comment: @Rechlay That could be `plot(x = unclass(table(tbl_sum_peaks)), y = names(table(tbl_sum_peaks)), type = "b")`.