# How to create a Barplot from a matrix in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298737/creating-a-barplot-from-matrix)... however, I'm having trouble adapting my code to it.

I am trying to make a Barplot using symmetrical matrix data. Here's some example code:

```
n <- 5 # no of rows
p <- 5 # no of columns

# Create matrix of values
mat <- matrix(runif(n*p, 0, 1), nrow=n) # create matrix     
colnames(mat) <- paste0("x", 1:p)  # column names
rownames(mat) <- paste0("x", 1:nrow(mat)) # row names

diag(mat) <- 0 # set diagonals to 0
mat <- (mat+t(mat))/2  # make matrix symmetrical


# Base-R barplot:
barplot(mat, beside = T,
        col = c("red","green", "yellow", "blue", "black"))
```

This will produce something like this:

[image: Base R barplot]

But what I'm trying to achieve is something more like this:
[image: ggplot barplot]

But I'm not sure exactly how I would achieve this. Below is an idea of how I would do it, but Im not sure:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mat, aes(x = variable names, y = values)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = values)) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "floralwhite",
                         high = "dodgerblue4") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_flip()
```

But since `mat` is in matrix format is can't do the above... and I don't know what exactly to put as the aesthetics?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is second plot supposed to graph? Sum of x and y pairings?

Comment: The 2 plots are displaying the same thing. The specific values might be different because  I used `runif`... but they're basically plotting the same thing. For example, in the 1st group in the 1st plot, it's showing x1 against (x2,x3,x4,x5) etc. for all the variables. The 2nd plot also show this but they are just ordered according to their value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider reshaping matrix data long via data frame operations:

```
# CONVERT TO DATA FRAME
df <- transform(data.frame(mat), y=row.names(mat))

# RESHAPE LONG
long_df <- reshape(df, varying = colnames(mat), times = colnames(mat),
                   timevar="x", v.names="value", direction="long")

# ORDER VALUES
long_df <- with(long_df, long_df[order(value),])
long_df$xy <- with(long_df, paste(x, y, sep=":"))

# CONVERT TO MATRIX
new_mat <- matrix(long_df$value, dimnames=list(long_df$xy, "value"))
new_mat

# BASE R barplot:
barplot(new_mat, beside = TRUE, horiz = TRUE, 
        main = "Horizontal Bar Graph Descending Order",
        names.arg = row.names(new_mat),
        las=1, col = rainbow(nrow(new_mat)))
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/NWHX78782)</kbd> *(click Run for plot)*

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: Very nice solution. Thanks

Comment: Any suggestions as to how I would produce this in ggplot?

Comment: Forgive me, but was that your original question? Per title and first attempt, you asked on `barplot`. Nonetheless, follow same data wrangling concepts (reshape long, re-order column by values, create `xy` column) then plot as a simple horizontal bar graph.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to do something like this ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

pivot_longer(data.frame(mat), cols = everything()) %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(newname = unique(.$name), 
          newname = paste(pmin(name, newname), 
                          pmax(name, newname), sep = ":")) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-name) %>%
   distinct() %>%
   arrange(value)  %>%
   mutate(newname = factor(newname, unique(newname))) %>%
   ggplot() + aes(x = newname, y = value, group = value, fill = value) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
   theme_minimal() + 
   theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5)) + 
   coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly, that gives a stacked barchart. I'm trying to make it more like the second example image I posted above

Comment: However, upon seeing your solution, I realised there was an error in my code. There shouldn't be any negative values. I changed `rnorm` to `runif` in the question.

Comment: Updated the answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: That's a nice solution. Is there any way to explicitly label each column and maybe order them according to their value?

Comment: 1) Aren't the colummns already labelled? (`x1` to `x5`) 2) Ordering them by which value?

Comment: 1) For example, in the x1 group, I know they are in the order x2,x5,x3,x4 starting from the bottom and going up. But I had to compare the groups to work that out. I was wondering if it's possible to have a label for each individual column. Not unlike the example in the question.
2) I meant order them from lowest to highest values. Lowest at the bottom, highest at the top... Is this possible?